# How to bind resources properties in a DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Hello all I have the following data template:

```
    <DataTemplate DataType="Integer">
        <StackPanel>
            <xctk:IntegerUpDown Minimum="{Binding XPath=Min}"
                                Maximum="{Binding XPath=Max}"
                                Increment="{Binding XPath=Inc}"
                                ClipValueToMinMax="True" 
                                AllowSpin="True">
                <xctk:IntegerUpDown.Resources>
                    <converters:Parameter x:Key="IntegerParameter"
                        CurrentDevice="{Binding ElementName=Dock, Path=DataContext.CurrentDevice}"
                        ParameterName="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, XPath=@RegisterName}"
                        ParameterType="Integer">
                    </converters:Parameter>
                </xctk:IntegerUpDown.Resources>
                <xctk:IntegerUpDown.Value>
                    <Binding XPath="@Name" 
                             Converter="{StaticResource IntegerDataConverter}" 
                             ConverterParameter="{StaticResource IntegerParameter}" 
                             Mode="TwoWay"/>
                </xctk:IntegerUpDown.Value>
            </xctk:IntegerUpDown>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Aim of this data template is to call the converter to set the value of the IntegerUpDown control reading it from an external device.

Details on how to contact the device are stored in the converters:Parameter class (derived from dependency object). Two way means that the same mechanism should be used with ConvertBack to write the value to the device.

MultiBinding is not an option since the ConvertBack method could not be used to "create" all the parameters from a single integer value.

This template works almost as intended: I get an instance of the Parameter class for each item the data template is applied to.

Unfortunately the values for CurrentDevice (that should bind to the DataContext property CurrentDevice of the window named "Dock") and ParameterName (that should bind to an Xml attribute of the Xml Node the DataTemplate is applied to) are always null.

I'm sure the issue is in the way I try to bind the Parameter properties, but I'm not able to figure out the correct syntax. Any idea on how to get the result (I can't believe this can't be done... ).

Thanks for any help you can provide

Comment: there's a XPath property on binding? are you sure that's right and you don't mean to use "Path" ? I've never heared of that property nor noticed it in intellisense

Comment: Yes there is. In fact my converter gets the value of Name attribute as value formal parameter. You use XPath instead of Path when your itemsource is an XmlDocument.

Comment: Interesting to know i guess. never had a scenario where my itemssource was an XmlDocument. Howeveri can give you one advice: Textblock Text="{Binding Path=.} helped me find many binding issues in WPF.

Answer (score 0):

As you may guess my idea was trying to find a workaround for the "you can't bind ConverterParameter" issue.

After further research on internet I found this post:

[Bindable Converter Parameter](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/456589/Bindable-Converter-Parameter)

from this ntg123 guy. It actually solves my problem allowing to somehow bind the ConverterParameter to multiple sources using a syntax almost identical to the standard one.

It is based on a custom MarkupExtension and works really well in situations where Multibinding is not possible.